# Java 9 Modules: Can automatic Modules result in larger (full) projects?

Tags: classpath, java-9, java-module

I guess automatic modules:

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules

means that each module of a project that requires a 3rd party jar will have to package that jar inside it's own *modular jar*. If that is the case couldn't a large multi-module application end up larger than its Java 8, classpath-based, counterpart? I'm thinking of all the nearly ubiquitous apache libraries and other common open source dependencies.

I get the win in the future; that all these 3rd party libraries would themselves be modularised and, therefore, only need to distribute a minimal configuration. But, in the short term, without a classpath, wouldn't there be some very bulky modular jars out there? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how automatic modules work. Their critical property is that you can use existing, non-modular JARs, put them on the module path and have them appear as modules for compilation or at run time.

> I guess automatic modules means that each module of a project that requires a 3rd party jar will have to package that jar inside it's own modular jar.

No, not at all. Quite the opposite, you reuse existing JARs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm sure I will accept the answer, please humour me for a while longer: In that case, I'm imagining an application jar, potentially containing multiple modules (also jars) packaged inside, along side them are 3rd party jars (e.g. guava, lombok, apache stuff), which many of them may depend on. Wouldn't that require some sort of classpath? I understood that modules would eradicate the classpath and the 'hell' that goes along with it. Where am I going wrong in my understanding of this?

Comment: Delivering a JAR containing other JARs is a process I am not familiar with - it requires a special class loader and I assume it is not very common. I have no idea how the module system would interact with it beyond the assumption that everything ends up in the unnamed module.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and comment imply that the classpath is going away: it is not.

Before addressing automatic modules, there are other concepts to understand.

In Java 9, the classpath is still around, and familiar legacy jars (i.e. non-modularized jars) will still work. However, there is also a new modulepath which contains modular jars.

Modular jars contain a `module-info.class` which is very explicit about (a) the modules required as dependencies and (b) which packages are exported.

A crucial point is the interaction between the classpath and the modulepath:

- Legacy jars on the classpath don't know anything about the modulepath, so they are granted access to all modules.
- Because the classpath is generally chaotic, it is known as the *unnamed module*. Because there is no name, modular jars on the modulepath can't reference legacy jars in their `module-info.java`.

With this much information, it would be impossible to modularize a project in a piecemeal fashion: if an application jar requires a 3rd-party library, we would have to (a) wait for the library authors to modularize it or (b) attempt to modularize it ourselves. Both are non-starters.

Enter *automatic modules*. They are legacy (non-modular) jars which reside on the modulepath. They act as the bridge between the classpath and the modulepath because:

- Automatic modules are named (the mechanism is a probably a separate question), and can be referenced by modules.
- Automatic modules are granted read access to everything in the unnamed module (i.e. legacy jars on the classpath) and all modules on the modulepath (i.e. JDK modules).

[This video](https://youtu.be/TEoexFsDP6A?t=24m3s) and [this video](https://youtu.be/fxB9cVNcyZo?t=21m44s) offer illustrations.